# ResourceNotFound: xarco

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to write a launch file for a URDF. When I run  `rosrun xacro xacro workcell.xarco` the ,xarco runs no problem, but when I run my .launch file I get

```
ResourceNotFound: xarco
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/donni/ROS_ws/ind_ws/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share
```

Also, when I run `rospack find xarco`, ros doese not find xarco. How is ros able to run xarco using rosrun, but can't find it with rospack. Also, how do I add xarco to my ros environment?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262078/resourcenotfound:-xarco/) by [dshimano](https://answers.ros.org/users/19862/dshimano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 129 on 2017-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have the `r` and the `c` in the wrong order.

It's `xacro`, not `xarco`.

And the `xacro` package is almost certainly part of the default ROS install, so you should already have it.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1